# I used colorpicker jquery plug to change backgound colors. how do i save the color code in Mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I used [this plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/).
how do get the hex value and post into database by using php/ajax jquery

My code is,

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
color: '#0000ff',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
},
onHide: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
},
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            $('#header').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);

}
});
```

Comment: You need to pass the color in `onChange` function to an ajax function, which will request a php file to save the color in database.

Comment: there no id then how did i get value onchange into ajax function.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed only the `onChange` function in your code

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        $('#header').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'some.php',
            data: { 'color': hex },
            success:function(result) {
                alert('color saved');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Based on this, the `some.php` file will save the color in database.

Comment: php jquery still probs : $sql="INSERT INTO colorcoder (colorhex) VALUES('$_POST[hex]')";

Comment: still not save into database :  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO colorcoder (colorhex)
VALUES('$_POST[color]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: Sorry for later answer, but what errors do you get?